# How to break html into <div> sections using jsdom

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

I have automatically generated HTML structure like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <h2>Subheading A</h2>
    <p>Subheading content 1</p>
    <ul>
      <li>bla</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Subheading content 2</p>
    <h2>Subheading B</h2>
    <p>Subheading content 1</p>
    <p>Subheading content 2</p>
    <p>Subheading content 3</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Html could have any number of Subheadings (h2).
- There could be any number of HTML elements between Subheadings.
- I want to wrap every subheading and following tags into a `<div>`

Here is an example

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
        <div>
          <h2>Subheading A</h2>
          <p>Subheading content 1</p>
          <ul>
            <li>bla</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Subheading content 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Subheading B</h2>
          <p>Subheading content 1</p>
          <p>Subheading content 2</p>
          <p>Subheading content 3</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

That is some code I've come up with

```
const dom = new JSDOM(myHtmlString);

orig_html = dom.window.document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML;
new_html = "<div>" + org_html + "</div>";
dom.window.document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = new_html;
```

However, I need to find all the elements that will belong to the current h2 and split the HTML into sections to do so. Do you have any ideas what is the best way to achieve that?

UPDATE:

What do you think, may be using `jsdom` in that case is not a best idea? Would it be better just achieving that outcome using text manipulation?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There is no benefit

Comment: @mousetail I need to group this way to apply styling to that html sections

Comment: Much easier to fix the source HTML than try to do this in JS

Comment: @mousetail this is automatically generated html

Comment: Can you not tweak the auto generation process?

Comment: @mousetail nope

Answer (score 1):

Determine all `<h2>` elements (for example, with `document.querySelectorAll`) and then, for each `<h2>`, start a new `<div>` that contains it and all following siblings until meeting another `<h2>`.

```js
var new_html = "";
for (var h2 of document.querySelectorAll("h2")) {
  if (!new_html) // include preamble before first h2
    for (var content, section = document.evaluate("preceding-sibling::*", h2,
         () => {}, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE);
     content = section.iterateNext(); )
      new_html += content.outerHTML;
  new_html += "<div>" + h2.outerHTML;
  for (var elem = h2;
       (elem = document.evaluate("following-sibling::*[1]", elem,
        () => {}, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE)) &&
       elem.nodeName !== "h2"; )
    new_html += elem.outerHTML;
  new_html += "</div>"
}
document.body.innerHTML = new_html;
```

This solution works properly only if all `<h2>` elements are on the same level.

But it is anyway unclear what you would want in case of

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<h2>My Second Heading</h2>
<div>
  Some text.
  <h2>A Heading At the Wrong Level</h2>
  Some more text.
</div>
```

Comment: yes, they are on the same level. however I just wonder would it be easier to achieve same outcome using text manipulation? (probably not, right?)

Comment: Text manipulation is an equally valid alternative.

Comment: If I have HTML actually started from the H2 `<h2>My First Heading</h2>` heading instead H1 heading, will it simplify the implementation?

Comment: In that case, rhe preamble inclusion can be omitted.

Answer (score -3):

One Solution could be You should use defined custom id name for heading and subheading so that when you traverse the dom you know where the breakpoint exits and there i have to stop . Like define id for subheading "subheading1" and add elements until you find "subheading2".

Comment: What would the code look like?

Comment: For a better answer you can show the implementation and explain it, but also the author said in the comments that they cannot change the source html, so defining  custom IDs doesn't seem possible for this case